# SQL comparing two date columns and keep the first row where 2nd column is larger

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a table with two date columns `next_start_date` and `cancel_date`.

| group_id | individual_id | cancel_date | next_start_date_after_cancel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2017-11-06 | 2014-03-26 |
| 1 | 001 | 2017-11-06 | 2017-01-09 |
| 1 | 001 | 2017-11-06 | 2018-04-16 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-06-04 | 2014-03-26 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-06-04 | 2017-01-09 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-06-04 | 2018-04-16 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-08-28 | 2014-03-26 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-08-28 | 2017-01-09 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-08-28 | 2018-04-16 |

Desired output: `days_customer_came_back` is a calculated column:

| group_id | individual_id | cancel_date | next_start_date_after_cancel | days_customer_came_back |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 2017-11-06 | 2018-04-16 | 161 |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-06-04 | null | null |
| 2 | 001 | 2018-08-28 | null | null |

The idea is I want to compare the two columns `cancel_date` and `next_start_date_after_cancel`, the `next_start_date_after_cancel` has to be after the `cancel_date` for us to obtain a positive day difference between these dates.

If there are multiple 'next_start_date_after_cancel' with respect to the same `cancel_date`, we keep the first minimum one only, while others are ignored.

Additionally, if for an entry of `cancel_date` if all the available `next_start_date_after_cancel` are before the cancel_date, we will replace it will null and the day difference will be output as null

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FILTER` to exclude the `cancel_date` that are greater than `next_start_date_after_cancel`, get the `min()` value of it inside a subquery or CTE. Finally subtract the two dates to get the different in days:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT 
    group_id,individual_id,cancel_date,
    min(next_start_date_after_cancel) FILTER (WHERE next_start_date_after_cancel > cancel_date) AS next_start_date_after_cancel
  FROM t GROUP BY 1,2,3)
SELECT 
  group_id,individual_id,cancel_date,next_start_date_after_cancel,
  next_start_date_after_cancel-cancel_date
FROM j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1856b02f26954e22e8a65cf719896293)

Comment: The filter didn't work for me, but I try to do it in a different way with case when comparing the next start date with cancel date. Thank you thought